# Adding track button to WooCommerce orders page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add track order button to My Account > Orders page to let visitors check shipping tracking from there. The button has a link to tracking service with tracking number gathered from public order notes (this is how tracking number is stored in my case). I managed to create "track" button but "view" buttons disappeared for following orders. It looks this way when code is applied - https://gyazo.com/498975ca43b09bce231a527ee782729a, second and third orders are supposed to have "view" buttons. 
AFAIK this is because these orders lack public order notes from where tracking number is gathered, but I can't understand how it can affect "view" buttons.

Here is my code:

```php
function my_code_add_myaccount_order_track_button( $actions, $order ) {
    $order_notes = $order->get_customer_order_notes();
    foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
    $actions['track'] = array(
        'url'  => 'https://t.17track.net/en#nums=' . substr($order_note->comment_content, strpos($order_note->comment_content, "number:") + 8, 13),
        'name' => __( 'Track', 'my-textdomain' ),
    );
    return $actions;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'my_code_add_myaccount_order_track_button', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: What does add_filter - this is not sufficient code fragment.

Comment: it's using a hook to insert my code and alter orders page

Comment: Most likely tracking code replace whole element instead just add click event, so it produces error when it can't get public order notes so code does not execute and button is not added - but it's just assumption, because you don't show whole relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. This is the only code needed for this function to work. There's no extra code related to this.

Comment: Where and how is executed `my_code_add_myaccount_order_track_button` what are the parameters, how actually works `add_filter`...? Don't expect everyone use your wordpress plugins, your setup and knows what actually happend to the button without looking at more code. Code you provided DOES NOT CHANGE DOM, so the problem is somewhere else, in code you not provided.

Comment: Here's the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions` hook - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-account-functions.php#L302,

`add_filter()` is a native WP function - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix this adding a function to bail if there are no public order comments for particular order. Here's the code:

```php
function my_code_add_myaccount_order_track_button( $actions, $order ) {
    $order_notes = $order->get_customer_order_notes();
        if ( empty ($order_notes) ) {
            return $actions;
        }
        else {
            foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
                $actions['track'] = array(
                    'url'  => 'https://t.17track.net/en#nums=' . substr($order_note->comment_content, strpos($order_note->comment_content, "number:") + 8, 13),
                    'name' => __( 'Track', 'my-textdomain' ),
                );
                return $actions;
            }
        }
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'my_code_add_myaccount_order_track_button', 10, 2 );
```